# How do I sync my search state with Url and connect it to next.js router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I am following the react instant search example here - https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/routing-urls/react/

```
const createURL = state => `?${qs.stringify(state)}`;

const searchStateToUrl = searchState =>
  searchState ? createURL(searchState) : '';

const urlToSearchState = ({ search }) => qs.parse(search.slice(1));
```

An I'm having difficulty understanding how this would work in next js, because how can I connect the `searchStateToUrl` function to my next router, since I am not accepting any props in next js?

```
export function App({ location, history }) {
  const [searchState, setSearchState] = useState(urlToSearchState(location));
  const debouncedSetStateRef = useRef(null);

  function onSearchStateChange(updatedSearchState) {
    clearTimeout(debouncedSetStateRef.current);

    debouncedSetStateRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      history.push(searchStateToUrl(location, updatedSearchState));
    }, DEBOUNCE_TIME);

    setSearchState(updatedSearchState);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchState(urlToSearchState(location));
  }, [location]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you saw this example from Vercel?

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-algolia-react-instantsearch/pages/index.js

This example is done with classes, but the only thing you have to change is tho way to capture the path because with next you are not using `react-router`.

Just change the function `searchStateToUrl` and the `useEffect` in the Algolia docs example to the following and should work.

```
const searchStateToUrl = (searchState) =>
  searchState ? `${window.location.pathname}?${qs.stringify(searchState)}` : "";
```

and

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchState(urlToSearchState({ search: window.location.search.slice(1) }));
  }, [location]);
```

Comment: i see you got the location as a dependancy in the useeffect, however what is it and where does it come from?